# Error 1180 at AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

i am building a game on flash cs5. i am making the start screen, and now i try to load the game but I get an error 1180 at my play game function. here is how it works

this is the function were i get the error at line this.stageRef. This class is my mainMenu which extends basemenu.

```
private function playGame(e:MouseEvent) : void
    {
        unload();
        this.stageRef.dispatchEvent(new Event("gameSTART"));
    }
```

and here is my engine function

```
public function Engine() 
    {
        preloader = new ThePreloader(474, this.loaderInfo);
        stage.addChild(preloader);
        preloader.addEventListener("loadComplete", loadAssets);
        preloader.addEventListener("preloaderFinished", showMenu);
        stage.addEventListener("gameSTART", fGameStart);
    }

    private function fGameStart(e:Event):void 
            {

                     .......... here is all my game code
            }
```

Comment: the code you provided doesn't really help. I suppose `stageRef` is null wnen you call playGame but can't be more helpful without the relevant code.

Comment: do you mean that part?

    `  public function MainMenu(stageRef:Stage = null ) 
  {
   this.stageRef = stageRef;
   btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, playGame, false, 0, true);
   btnCredits.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, credits,  false, 0, true);
  }`

I dunno how to make it to be in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, your stageRef is not proper EventDispatcher object. Either you have another custom Stage class, or when you get stage property with Stage object the owner of this property is not on the stage yet. So try to get stage property after Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE event of the source object. Or show your code where you get Stage and pass to the MainMenu.

Answer (score 0):

make stageRef class implement IEventDispatcher